# CSS issue in a MVC 5 application

Tags: css, model-view-controller

It's an MVC 5 app.

I'm simply trying to get a Menu item to be a different color than the others to indicate what view is being shown. The HOME view is shown at startup and I want the home view nav bar item to be a different background and text color.

I have a Site.css file with the CSS rule I am trying to apply and it does not seem to take affect.

Other rules in the file do take affect as I can do an inspection and see that it does see the Site.css file.

I added the Site.css file to the BundleConfig.css.

```
        // Added my custom.css in the css bundle.
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/custom.css"));
```

Here is the code in the _Layout.cshtml file:
[image]

Here is the inspection of the HTML/CSS:
[image]

Here is the Site.css file:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the styles for wrong elements. If you want to apply the background and color for active links, you have to apply like below.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
   color:#428bca;
   background-color:#e7e7e7;
 }
```

Suppose if you are not able to the updates after applying this style then may be the default bootstrap style will overwritting your styles. In that time, use `important` keyword to make your styles overwrite the bootstrap styles.

```
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
   color:#428bca !important;
   background-color:#e7e7e7 !important;
 }
```

Comment: That worked - the Home name bar item is highlighted accordingly...but now this leads me to another problem. Once I navigate to another view using the nav bar, how do I unhighlight that Home nav bar item and highlight the item for the view I am now at?

Comment: I want to change the name of the class from "active" to "homelink". I adjust the CSS rule - replacing "active" to "homelink". I also adjusted the HTML as well. Now it won't work. It will only work if it is called "active". Why?